# Convert MS SQL image column values to bit or int 0/1

Tags: sql-server

A shrink-wrapped product's database maintained by a vendor contains a table of people where some of them have pictures in another child table. I need to determine in SQL statement who have pictures and who don't and raise a flag.

What would be the select statement to convert an image column to 0 or 1 depending on whether there is an image value in the row as below?

Data:

```
photo
------------
null
@$@#$#@$#@$#&^$%^%53452^#$%#5...
```

Result:

```
photoFlag
-----------
0
1
```

Of course it could be done on the client in the code, but I don't want to bring the image values across the network and into the client address space.

I could not think of anything better than

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(1), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),photo)) AS photoFlag FROM photos
```

and then calling .IsNull on the client. But I am not linking it as it's not elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using `CASE()`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN photo IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS photoFlag FROM photos
```

Comment: Forgot about cases. Thanks!